# Why does this added UI button's event not get called?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cities-skylines-api

In developing a mod for Cities: Skylines, I have run across a problem.

Most of my code, as far as I can tell, works fine - but so far, I haven't got to test it. This is because it should all get called in sequence when a button I have added to the UI gets clicked. The click event on this button is not calling the handler I've assigned to it.

This is where I create the button:

```
public class LoadingExtension : LoadingExtensionBase
{
    public override void OnLevelLoaded(LoadMode mode)
    {
        Debug.LogDebugMessage("Adding 'Generate City Report' button to UI");

        // Get the UIView object. This seems to be the top-level object for most
        // of the UI.
        var uiView = UIView.GetAView();

        // Add a new button to the view.
        var button = (UIButton)uiView.AddUIComponent(typeof(UIButton));

        // Set the text to show on the button.
        button.text = "Generate City Report";

        // Set the button dimensions.
        button.width = 250;
        button.height = 30;

        // Style the button to look like a menu button.
        button.normalBgSprite = "ButtonMenu";
        button.disabledBgSprite = "ButtonMenuDisabled";
        button.hoveredBgSprite = "ButtonMenuHovered";
        button.focusedBgSprite = "ButtonMenuFocused";
        button.pressedBgSprite = "ButtonMenuPressed";
        button.textColor = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
        button.disabledTextColor = new Color32(7, 7, 7, 255);
        button.hoveredTextColor = new Color32(7, 132, 255, 255);
        button.focusedTextColor = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
        button.pressedTextColor = new Color32(30, 30, 44, 255);

        // Enable button sounds.
        button.playAudioEvents = true;

        // Place the button.
        button.transformPosition = new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.97f);

        // Respond to button click.
        // NOT GETTING CALLED
        button.eventClick += ButtonClick;
    }

    public void ButtonClick(UIComponent component, UIMouseEventParameter eventParam)
    {
        Debug.LogWarningMessage("HIGH LOGIC: Beginning report generation.");
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString();
        string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string filename = filepath + "\\CityReport-" + now + ".xlsx";
        Output fileCreator = new Output(filename);
        fileCreator.GenerateReport();
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://skylines-modding-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modding/Development/How-to-Use-ColossalFramework.UI.html) I've been following, using

```
button.eventClick += ButtonClick;
```

should add `ButtonClick` as the click handler for the button. However, clicking on the button does nothing. The debug message at the start of the handler (the "HIGH LOGIC" message) doesn't get displayed (note: the earlier debug message about adding the button to the UI does). No error messages are displayed either in the game's debug panel or in VS.

I have also tried using `new MouseEventHandler(ButtonClick)`, since the VS inline documentation tells me that the type of `eventClick` is `MouseEventHandler`. This doesn't show any errors in VS or the game, but doesn't work either.

(Note: there *is* [official documentation](http://www.skylineswiki.com/Modding_API), but it's next to useless.)

Does anyone here have experience with the C:S API? Why is this event not getting called?

Answer (score 2):

You might try taking a small step back to check if a different UI element works; for example, by following the example for adding a [UILabel](http://skylines-modding-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modding/Development/How-to-Use-ColossalFramework.UI.html#adding-more-stuff-children).  Registering a click event handler to this one possibly might work, since there's an actual example to follow; although, the documentation says to place this code inside the Start method.  I'm not sure, but maybe the UIButton in your code should be placed in a Start method as well.

As an aside, I stumbled upon this link for [debugging](http://skylines-modding-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modding/Workflow/Debugging.html).  Skylines seems to have its own messaging system for debugging.

Something that I did notice in your code is that the first Debug statement uses a different method than the second Debug statement:

1. Debug.LogDebugMessage("Adding 'Generate City Report' button to UI");
2. Debug.LogWarningMessage("HIGH LOGIC: Beginning report generation.");

It might not make any difference, but I would test out that Debug.LogWarningMessage call by moving it where the Debug.LogDebugMessage is to see if it actually works.

According to the extremely terse documentation there's a log file called [output_log.txt](http://skylines-modding-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modding/Workflow/Output-Log.html), perhaps there might be some info contained within this file.

Comment: The two Debug methods are my own: they simply call an API debug method with slightly different parameters, which works fine. Good idea on taking a step back though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
//button.eventClick += ButtonClick;
button.eventClick += (c,e) => {
    Debug.LogWarningMessage("HIGH LOGIC: Beginning report generation.");
    string now = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString();
    string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string filename = filepath + "\\CityReport-" + now + ".xlsx";
    Output fileCreator = new Output(filename);
    fileCreator.GenerateReport();
};
```

Also have you tried doing this?:

```
//var button = (UIButton)uiView.AddUIComponent(typeof(UIButton));
var button = uiView.AddUIComponent(typeof(UIButton)) as UIButton
```

(Sorry, i can't coment yet)

Comment: Neither of these work, but thanks for trying anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your click handler, as such, is OK. Change your ButtonClick method to:

```
public void ButtonClick(UIComponent component, UIMouseEventParameter eventParam)
{
    Debug.LogWarningMessage("HIGH LOGIC: Beginning report generation.");
}
```

and then check the debug output. If you have a bug *after* that line, then the debug message may not be visible.